# Testing valid mail address using exec

Tags: javascript, regex

I have wrote the below function to validate the email address entered by user.

```
function checkEmail(v_email)
{
var l_ret=true;
var l_reg = /^[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9.-]{2,}[.][a-z]{2,3}$/;
if (l_reg.exec(v_email)==null){l_ret=false;}
return l_ret;
}
```

It works perfectly fine.. with lowercase email address, (example.myemail@example.com) but if it detect any capital letter then it fails. like (example.MYemail@example.com).

I am trying to make it work for both capital as well as lower letter but i am not able to make it.. any one good with regex..could please suggest.

thank you in advance...

regards,
Mona..

Comment: Of course this regular expression only matches a subset of valid email addresses, and including capitals will not improve the situation much. For something better see http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: [Stop Validating Email Addresses With Complicated Regular Expressions](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the case insensitive mode:

```
/^[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9.-]{2,}[.][a-z]{2,3}$/i;
                                            ^
```

It makes `[a-z]` also match uppercase letters. Otherwise, you can use `[A-Za-z]` to mean both upper and lowercase characters in regex.

Comment: Hi Jerry.. thank you for reply.. just would like to know the above my regex will validate whole email address or just part..as JON said above...so thought will ask you..

Comment: even space is a valid character in emailid..so are ;:^&#!()%...Don't use regex to parse email..plz

Comment: @monamona Yes, I know. I simply answered your question; which was to make the regex work for both uppercase and lowercase letters. Parsing valid email addresses is another question and the site has a lot of duplicate questions like that.

Comment: @monamona:- You may find this Thread helpful:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable answers... at this moment this solved my purpose.. so i will go ahead with this. thank you once again..

Answer (score 1):

Noooooooooooo you **DONT** use regex to validate EMAIL..

An Email is valid if you can send a mail to it..

To validate Email,follow these steps..

- 1>Send Mail to that email address in which you can put an activation code or even a link.
- 2>If you receive the respose,email is valid..

---

At max your regex should be

```
^[^@]+@[^@]+$
```

[Stop Validating Email Addresses With Complicated Regular Expressions](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/)

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex like this:

```
var l_reg = /^[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9.-]{2,}[.][a-z]{2,3}$/i;
```

instead of

```
 var l_reg = /^[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9.-]{2,}[.][a-z]{2,3}$/;
```

Comment: even space is a valid character in emailid..so are ;:^&#!()%...Don't use regex to parse email..plz

Comment: @Anirudh:- Very correct! But OP's question is very specific: **I am trying to make it work for both capital as well as lower letter but i am not able to make it**

Answer (score 0):

Make the regex ignore the case by adding the flag `i` like below:

```
var l_reg = /^[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9.-]{2,}[.][a-z]{2,3}$/i;
```

Comment: even space is a valid character in emailid..so are ;:^&#!()%...Don't use regex to parse email..plz

Comment: @Anirudh: I am not exactly recommending this method. I am merely answering the OP's question on how to make it ignore case.